# Optional fields in run-types

Tags: typescript, types, runtypes

Assuming we have following code:

```
export const UserInfoResponse = Record({
  userId: String,
  userName: String,
  userEmail: String,
  permissions: Array(String),
  roles: Array(Record({ id: String, name: String })),
}).And(
  Partial({
    givenName: String,
    familyName: String,
  }),
);
```

what is the difference between the code?

```
export const UserInfoResponse = Record({
  userId: String,
  userName: String,
  userEmail: String,
  permissions: Array(String),
  roles: Array(Record({ id: String, name: String })),
  givenName?: String,
  familyName?: String,
);
```

It is not the same? I guess that it is not the same but have no idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const UserInfoResponse = Record({
  userId: String,
  userName: String,
  userEmail: String,
  permissions: Array(String),
  roles: Array(Record({ id: String, name: String })),
  givenName?: String,
  familyName?: String,
);
```

This syntax is invalid, you can't write `givenName?: String` or `familyName?: String` like that in an object. The question mark operator to denote an optional property is only valid on the type-level, but not on the runtime-level (here you are defining a `const` not a `type` or `interface`)